# Castle Active Record - object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: nhibernate, configuration, castle-activerecord

Hi this is my first attempt with Active Record I use tutorial from official web site.

First I created some etities:

```
[ActiveRecord("Users")]
public class User : ActiveRecordBase<User>
{
    private IList<PhotoAlbum> _albums = new List<PhotoAlbum>();

    [PrimaryKey]
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo("ProfilId")]
    public virtual Profil Profil { get; set; }

    [HasMany(typeof(PhotoAlbum),Table = "PhotoAlbums",
        ColumnKey = "UserId", 
        Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.AllDeleteOrphan)]
    public IList<PhotoAlbum> Album
    {
        get { return _albums; }
        set { _albums = value; }
    }

    [Property]
    public virtual string AzetId { get; set; }
    [Property]
    public virtual string Nick { get; set; }
    [Property]
    public virtual string SelfNick { get; set; }
}

[ActiveRecord("Profiles")]
public class Profil : ActiveRecordBase<Profil>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int ProfilId { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [Property]
    public int Sex { get; set; }
    [Property]
    public string Region { get; set; }
    [Property]
    public string Town { get; set; }
    [Property]
    public bool WithPhoto { get; set; }
    [Property]
    public bool HasPhotoAlbum { get; set; }
}

[ActiveRecord("PhotoAlbums")]
public class PhotoAlbum : ActiveRecordBase<PhotoAlbum>
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int PhotoAlbumId { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Property]
    public int NumberOfPhoto { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created xml config file for active record:

```
<activerecord>
  <config>
    <add
      key="hibernate.connection.driver_class"
      value="NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver" />
    <add
      key="dialect"
      value="NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect" />
    <add
      key="connection.provider"
      value="NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider" />
    <add
      key="connection.connection_string"
      value="Data Source=test\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=TEST_AR_POKEC;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
  </config>

</activerecord>
```

Finnaly I tested:

```
    public static User GetUser(string nick, int sex,
        string loc)
    {
        return new User
        {
            AzetId = new Random().Next()
            .ToString(),
            Nick = nick,
            SelfNick = nick.ToUpper(),
            Profil = new Profil()
            {
                Sex = sex,
                Region = loc,
                WithPhoto = true,
                Age = new Random().Next(6, 99),
                HasPhotoAlbum = true,
                Town = loc
            },
            Album = new List<PhotoAlbum>
                                         {
                                             new PhotoAlbum
                                                 {
                                                     Name = "Me",
                                                     NumberOfPhoto =new Random().Next()
                                                 }
                                         }

        };
    }


        var source = new XmlConfigurationSource("ac.xml");

        ActiveRecordStarter.Initialize(source,typeof(Profil),typeof(PhotoAlbum), typeof(User));
        ActiveRecordStarter.CreateSchema();

        var user = GetUser("tom",1,"DC");
        user.Create();
```

It finished with this error:

> The ProxyFactoryFactory was not configured. Initialize
>   'proxyfactory.factory_class' property of the session-factory
>   configuration section with one of the available NHibernate.ByteCode
>   providers.

I google it and I think I found aswer I modified xml config for active record I added this part:

```
 <add
      key="proxyfactory.factory_class"
      value="NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle"/>
```

I tested again. It created tabels in DB but this didn’t insert data to tables and I got this error:

> object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient
>   instance before flushing.

Here is StackTrace :

> at
>   NHibernate.Engine.ForeignKeys.GetEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(String
>   entityName, Object entity, ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Type.EntityType.GetIdentifier(Object value,
>   ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Type.ManyToOneType.IsDirty(Object old, Object current,
>   Boolean[] checkable, ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Type.TypeHelper.FindDirty(StandardProperty[] properties,
>   Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, Boolean[][]
>   includeColumns, Boolean anyUninitializedProperties,
>   ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.FindDirty(Object[]
>   currentState, Object[] previousState, Object entity,
>   ISessionImplementor session)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.DirtyCheck(FlushEntityEvent
>   event)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.IsUpdateNecessary(FlushEntityEvent
>   event, Boolean mightBeDirty)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.OnFlushEntity(FlushEntityEvent
>   event)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.FlushEntities(FlushEvent
>   event)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.FlushEverythingToExecutions(FlushEvent
>   event)    at
>   NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent
>   event)    at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.Framework.SessionFactoryHolder.ReleaseSession(ISession
>   session)    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase.InternalCreate(Object instance,
>   Boolean flush)    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase.Create(Object instance)    at
>   Castle.ActiveRecord.ActiveRecordBase.Create()    at
>   SAMPLE_1.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\C#
>   PROJECTS\STUDY\STUDY.ORM\Active Record\SAMPLE_1\Program.cs:line 51
>   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly,
>   String[] args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String
>   assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Maybe problem is here:

```
[BelongsTo("ProfilId")]
public virtual Profil Profil { get; set; }
```

and

```
[HasMany(typeof(PhotoAlbum),Table = "PhotoAlbums",
    ColumnKey = "UserId", 
    Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.AllDeleteOrphan)]
public IList<PhotoAlbum> Album
{
    get { return _albums; }
    set { _albums = value; }
}
```

I am not sure but if I omitted these two properties (relationship) it works good and data are inserted into table. But with relationship doesn’t work.

EDITED:

If I specified Cascade behavior it works...but why?

```
   [BelongsTo("ProfilId", 
        Cascade =CascadeEnum.All)]
    public virtual Profil Profil { get; set; }

    [HasMany(typeof(PhotoAlbum), 
        Table = "PhotoAlbums",
        ColumnKey = "UserId",
        Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.All)]
    public IList<PhotoAlbum> Album
    {
        get { return _albums; }
        set { _albums = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not wanting the `Profile` to be saved with your `User` object automatically (`CascadeEnum.All`) you must save this object separately in your session before saving your `User`.

The reason it's throwing that exception when cascading is not turned on is because your `Profile` object within your `User` is `transient` (not saved).  If you turn on cascading it automatically saves your object and is therefore NOT `transient`.

#### Example with cascading

```
ISession.Save(user);
```

#### Example without cascading

```
ISession.Save(profile);
Isession.Save(user);
```